# BigQueryIO.Write in dataflow 2.X

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Below code worked for Dataflow 1.9 sdk, migrating to 2.X

```
PCollection<TableRow> tableRow = ...

tableRow.apply(BigQueryIO.Write()
                .to(String.format("%1$s:%2$s.%3$s",projectId, bqDataSet, bqTable))
                .withSchema(schema)
                .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

I get

```
The method apply(PTransform<? super PCollection<TableRow>,OutputT>) in the type PCollection<TableRow> is not applicable for the arguments (BigQueryIO.Write<Object>)
```

[Release notes](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-java-2) are not much of a help here and documentation on 2.X is non existant redirects to beam API page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using BigqueryIO.writeTableRows()?

Apache Beam 2.1.0 BigqueryIO documentation
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try providing `TableRow` type explicitly (`BigQuery.<TableRow>write()...`) or use `BigQuery.writeTableRows()` as suggested above.

Looks like the interface was made generic in 2.x. Earlier version had TableRow hard coded.